# SQL Query Run Against Excel Workbook Returns Truncated Text Field

Tags: sql, excel-2007, ado

I'm running a SQL SELECT query through an ADO connection to an Excel 2007 workbook with the following code (using a custom version of VBScript)

```
dim ado, rs
set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ado.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=workbook.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
ado.open()
set rs = ado.execute("SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]")
```

which is straighforward. The problem is that any cell that has text longer than 255 characters is truncated; is there any way around this? Is there a property in the connection string that will support this or is it an option I need to change in the excel document itself? I have tried MSSQL's CAST() function but this just causes an error when executed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have also noticed that sometimes it returns more that 255 characters, but the first 255 characters are from the correct cell and the remaining text is seemingly from a random cell (worryingly, the extra text is different each time).

Comment: this (random appended text) isn't the case when I use the 2003 file format and the Jet provider in the connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into a variant of a long-standing limitation in Excel's data access provider. See http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;189897 for an example or google for thousands more.

Comment: following the info given in the kb article, I changed the corresponding value in the registration key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel but this failed to correct the problem; changing to jet 4 with the above fix did work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use CAST(), have you tried to use the CONVERT() function?

Comment: I get an "Undefined function" error when using CONVERT, just tried it

Comment: @TheGravyTalker: Were you using Convert() correctly? Convert(varchar(500), FieldName)?